# Ubuntu 22.04 Lts No Audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.04, hdmi

I use an old PC as a media station / netflix machine, attached via HDMI to a Samsung TV. Everything worked fine in 20.04 and previous versions, but as I did a fresh install of 22.04 no audio is comin out from speakers.

Audio is not working via HDMI connection, but also with cable connected to the speakers from the audio card Line-Out.

I tried several solutions (grub edit, used alsamixer, reinstall alsa / pulse) but had no effect. I also installed "pavucontrol", and when I open it I can see audio on HDMI / Display port is "working" because the indicator is flashing as The music plays, but no audio at all is coming out from speakers.

I Would like to keep 22.04, otherwise I will roll back to 20.04 with a fresh install

Thanks all for help, hope someone will give me some ideas to solve the problem (I'm not a Linux expert, just a super noob)

Comment: Vague terms like old PC aren't helpful without some facts?  I'm replying here on a 2009 dell. but do you consider that old or not? and 2009 means nothing given I gave only the make (dell) anyway & have another PC from 2008 that contains much of the same hardware too. You gave no details as to which hardware stack you used with 20.04 (ie. was it GA or HWE; as there was less change to move from 20.04 if using HWE).  I'd likely have looked at how the 22.04 kernel saw your hardware (ie. `sudo lshw -C sound` to list-hardware of class sound) for details to peek at what 5.15 kernel of 22.04 saw